# Echoing PHP API Data In 3 Columns

Tags: php, html, api

I am getting website design ideas from a website API.

Currently my setup displays these designs in a table with only one column, I have over 40 items that need to be displayed in the table, but id prefer to display it in 3 columns. I have tried using i=0 ++ things etc but couldnt work out where to put it.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php   


   $output = json_decode($output);
    curl_close($ch);
        echo '<table border="1">';
       foreach($output as $template) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $template->template_name . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>' . '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'. $template->preview_url .'" target="_blank"><img src="' . $template->thumbnail_url. '"></a>' . '</td>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><form method="GET" action=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="template_id" value="' . $template->template_id . '">';
        echo '<input type="url" name="original_url" placeholder="Existing Site URL">'.'<br />';
        echo '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required>'.'<br />';
        echo '<button type="submit">Choose Site</button>';
        echo '</form></td>';


        echo '</tr>';

    }


    echo '</table>';
}


?>
```

The output includes all of the website templates.
I am putting it into rows.The first row contains the name of the template, the second the picture of the website template and the third a form which I am working on.

My question is how can I nest the loop so that it does 3 columns, each row with 3 different designs?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I dont use PHP much, my site is in Wordpress but to use the API white labelled system i am integrating I must use the api files and customise it for my site. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common idea may be as the following, for example:

```
<?php


$array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$i = 1;

echo "<table>";
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
       echo "<tr class='class_3'>";
    } else if ($i % 2 === 0) {
       echo "<tr class='class_2'>";
    } else {
       echo "<tr class='class_1'>";
    }

    echo '<td>'.($i++).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.($i++).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.($i++).'</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
    //$i++; for 123 456
}
echo '</table>';            

?>
```

---

Update: a more specific example:

```
<?php

$assoc_array = json_decode('
[
   {"template_id": "1","template_name":"A", "preview_url":"url_1"},
   {"template_id": "2","template_name":"B", "preview_url":"url_2"},
   {"template_id": "3","template_name":"C", "preview_url":"url_3"},
   {"template_id": "4","template_name":"D", "preview_url":"url_4"},
   {"template_id": "5","template_name":"E", "preview_url":"url_5"},
   {"template_id": "6","template_name":"F", "preview_url":"url_6"},
   {"template_id": "7","template_name":"G", "preview_url":"url_7"},
   {"template_id": "8","template_name":"H", "preview_url":"url_8"},
   {"template_id": "9","template_name":"I", "preview_url":"url_9"},
   {"template_id": "10","template_name":"J", "preview_url":"url_10"}
]
', true);

echo '<table>';
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($assoc_array); $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
       echo "<tr class='class_3'>";
    } else if ($i % 2 === 0) {
       echo "<tr class='class_2'>";
    } else {
       echo "<tr class='class_1'>";
    }   

    echo '<td>'.$assoc_array[$i]['template_name'].'</td>';

    if(isset($assoc_array[++$i]['template_name'])) {
       echo '<td>'.$assoc_array[$i]['template_name'].'</td>';
    }

    if(isset($assoc_array[++$i]['template_name'])) {
       echo '<td>'.$assoc_array[$i]['template_name'].'</td>';
    }       

    echo '</tr>';        
}
echo '</table>';    
?>
```

You'll get:

```
A       B       C   
D       E       F   
G       H       I   
J
```

Comment: Thanks, but trying this only displays the same result 3 times in 3 columns
it is coming out as:
000
111
222

What i am looking for is
123
456

Is this possible? :-) Thanks

Comment: I am substituting the ($i++) inide the 3 <td>s with my own value which is . $template->template_name .

So for example im using 3 lots of 
 echo '<td>'. $template->template_name . '</td>';
inside the statement you provided. How can i increment these template names so that it doesnt display the same thing 3 times on each row?
Your example works fine but that is because it is using ++ to increment, how can I increment my templates? Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who contributed. My answer is now finished.
The final code was:

```
<?php

        $output = json_decode($output);
        curl_close($ch);



        $i = 0;
        echo '<table border="1" width="80%">';
         echo '<tr>';
        foreach($output as $template) {



        echo '<td><a href="'. $template->preview_url .'" target="_blank"><img src="' . $template->thumbnail_url. '" height="300" width="460"></a>' .'<br />';
        echo '<form method="GET" action=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="template_id" value="' . $template->template_id . '">';
        echo '<input type="url" name="original_url" placeholder="Existing Site URL">'.'<br />';
        echo '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required>'.'<br />';
        echo '<button type="submit">Choose Site</button>';
        echo '</form></td>';        

        $i++;



         if($i == 3) { // three items in a row. Edit this to get more or less items on a row
                            echo '</tr>'.'<tr>';
                            $i = 0;
                        }

    }

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
} 

?>
```